# How to sort a String array alphabetically (without using compareTo or Arrays.sort)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need to organize an array of Strings alphabetically. In theory, the first letter of each word is capitalized (although not necessarily, because one can't always trust users). I have tried `Arrays.sort()` and it won't run the program. I have tried using `compareTo()`, and while it runs the program, when it gets to that section of code, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.String.compareTo(Unknown Source)
    at NameandAge.printNameOrder(NameandAge.java:431)
    at NameandAge.print(NameandAge.java:350)
    at NameandAge.main(NameandAge.java:116)
```

Literally everything I can find on this subject gives me one of those two solutions. Any other suggestions?

(For the record, the code currently reads: )

```
while(!done)
{
    done=true;   
    for(int i=0;i<organizedNames.length-1;i++)
    {
        if(!(organizednames[i]==null))
        {
            String name1=organizedNames[i]; String name2=organizedNames[i+1];
            if(name1!=null&&name2!=null)
            {
                int num=name1.compareTo(name2);
                if(num>0)
                { 
                    temp=organizedNames[i]; //temp is a String that was declared earlier
                    organizedNames[i]=organizedNames[i+1];
                    organizedNames[i+1]=temp;
                    done=false 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Tried checking to make sure name1 and name2 weren't `null`. It works now, but this is the output:
     Joe
     Bill
     Bob
     Smith
     Rodney
     James
     Philip
     Lillian
     Charlie
     Angel
     Carol
     Noah
I added the whole section of code now(minus the while loop, of course). This is basically the exact solution I found, and the first one to give me any output at all. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT (again): This is the code that calls the sort.

```
String[]organizedNames=new String[names.length];
organizedNames=sortNames(organizedNames);
```

And the code for the sort itself is basically what's in the answer below.

Comment: No one will be able to answer you without seeing the `NameandAge` source code.

Comment: Why dont you actually post all the code for the while loop, so we can see where your problem is. I suspect the problem will be along the lines of if one item in the pair is null, you do nothing, wheras what you want to do is to set num to -1 when you find a null in one and to +1 when you find a null in the other.

Comment: Consider it done. Not sure how it helps though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running some variation of the bubble sort algorithm, and that you have not sanitised you input array for null strings, the problem is likely that `organizedNames[i]` is null.

If this is the case you need to decide if you want to remove null items, or list them at the end of the array. If the latter is true, prior to doing a comparison, check if `name1 == null || name2 == null` if so, set num to -1, this will put all the null items in an array in one place.

To answer your secondary question, try this:

```
boolean done = false;
while(done == false){
  done = true;
  for(int i=0;i<organizedNames.length-1;i++)
  {
    int num = 0;
    if(organizedNames[i] != null && organizedNames[i + 1] != null)
    {
        String name1=organizedNames[i]; String name2=organizedNames[i+1];
        num=name1.compareTo(name2);
    }
    else if(organizedNames[i] == null && organizedNames[i + 1] == null){
      num = 0;
    }
    else if(organizedNames[i] == null){
      num = 1;
    }
    else {
      num = -1;
    }
    if(num>0)
    {
        String temp=organizedNames[i];
        organizedNames[i]=organizedNames[i+1];
        organizedNames[i+1]=temp;
        done=false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I did (as the edit shows), just not in the way you had suggested. Gonna try it anyway, just in case.

Comment: Its been a while since I worked in Java, it turns out that if either String is null, you will get an error. So perform the same check on `organizedNames[i + 1]`. I edited my response to show this.

Comment: I tried your secondary suggestion, and got the same output as before.

Comment: what is the initial value of the array you are trying to sort?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but this is my answer to the question I think you're asking: The initial values are the names in the output, in that order, followed by a bunch of `null`s. That's probably completely unhelpful; could you  be a bit more specific?

Comment: if I run the following through the script it works correctly - for clarities sake, I have copied and pasted the EXACT code from my IDE, in case of C&P errors:

    String[] organizedNames = new String[14];
organizedNames[0] = "Bill";
organizedNames[1] = "Bob";
organizedNames[2] = "Smith";
organizedNames[3] = "Rodney";
organizedNames[4] = "James";
organizedNames[5] = "Philip";
organizedNames[6] = "Lillian";
organizedNames[7] = "Charlie";
organizedNames[8] = "Angel";
organizedNames[9] = "Carol";
organizedNames[11] = "Noah";
organizedNames[12] = null;
organizedNames[13] = null;

Comment: I have something similar in my program( `for(int i=0;i<names.length; i++){organizedNames[i]=names[i];}`, to be exact, where names is an array that is read in from a file and any spaces left unfilled are set to `null`). I can't do it your way because the file will not always read the same thing.

Comment: A nice concept of OO programming is that you can abstract things. Implement this method on its own in a function that takes in an array of strings. That way you can test the method to see if the sort works given a specific array, then implement a separate function that reads the input form a file, constructs the array - and calls the sort function. Another idea would be to truncate the array to remove the null strings, then you can call `Arrays.sort` on it without having to implement a sort routine yourself.

Comment: The good new is that the method works. The bad news is that I can't return a whole array - it doesn't give me an error, it just doesn't bother to do it. The array remains exactly the same. I can't do `Arrays.sort` because... reasons. I don't even know. I'm starting to feel like I'm banging my head against a wall repeatedly.

Comment: Put it up in the original question.

Comment: the code you provided will pass an empty array of null strings to the sort function.

Answer (score 1):

Using collections we can do like this..

```
SortedSet<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();
String[] s = { "this", "will", "be", "sorted", "without", "ba", "any", "sort()", "function", "or","comparator" };

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
        {
            set.add(s[i]);
        }

        for (Object element : set) {
            System.out.println(element.toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've gotten yourself into a right mess here!  What you've been trying to do is to implement your own sort algorithm from the ground up, without understanding why the original version wasn't working.  It didn't work ... for the same reason the original version didn't work.

If I am reading the evidence correctly, the *root cause* of your problems is the `null` values in your input array.  There are three simple ways to deal with this:

1. Get rid of the `null` values by creating a new (smaller) array with the nulls eliminated.
2. Replace the `null` values with some value (e.g. an empty `String`) that can be safely compared without causing an NPE.
3. Implement a `Comparator` that is tolerant of `null`s.  For example, if we wanted to make `null` sort after non-null strings ...

   ```
     public class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {
         public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
             if (s1 == null) {
                 return (s2 == null) ? 0 : +1;
             } else {
                 return (s2 == null) ? -1 : s1.compareTo(s2);
             }
         }
     }

     String[] array = ...
     Arrays.sort(array, new MyComparator());
   ```

If you are interested in why your code in the Question isn't sorting properly, it is because of your strategy for dealing with `null`.  Basically, the code (as written) compares successive pairs of array entries, swapping them if they are out of order.  When it makes a pass through the array that doesn't find anything to swap, it stops.  The problem is that if either of the elements it is comparing is `null`, it doesn't compare them.  So if you have a `null` in the array, any non-null elements before the `null` cannot be compared with any non-null elements after the `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, String class is immutable, i.e. no matter how you sort it or arrange it. It will never change the insertion order inside itself.

The reason for this is because when you create a String class object, a memory is allocated inside the String Constant/Literal Pool, which maybe be used by many other programs/methods that are concurrently running on the same JRE.

```
 class Test{  
 public static void main(String args[]){  
   String s="Jake";  
   s.concat(" Paul");//concat() method appends the string at the end  
   System.out.println(s);//will print Jake because strings are immutable objects  
 }  
}
```

Therefore, try the usual sorting algorithm wont work here.

You can how ever use StringBuilder instead of String. Since, StringBuilder is mutable, your manual sorting algorithms should work on them.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this Code which not use any Predefined** `Array.Sort()` and `compareTo()` **method**

```
sortStringArray(new String[]{"Henry Bernard",
            "Cherish Davidson",
            "Joshua Norris",
            "Eleanor Kelley",
            "Jaslyn Schneider",
            "Holly Herman",
            "Willie Strong",
            "Eliana Villa",
            "Lennon Odom",
            "Monica Velasquez",
            "Salvatore Levy",
            "Taliyah Bruce"});

public static void sortStringArray(String[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < array.length - i; j++) { //Apply the bubble Sort
            if (CompareString(array[j - 1], array[j]) == 1) { //Pass the two adjacent string for comparing
                String temp = array[j - 1];
                array[j - 1] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}

private static int CompareString(String first, String second) {
    int len;

    if (first.length() >= second.length()) //we need to take the smallest string length
        len = second.length();
    else
        len = first.length();

    for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
        if (first.charAt(i) > second.charAt(i))  //Suppose the first string letters is greater then return 1; 
            return 1;
        else if (first.charAt(i) < second.charAt(i)) //if second string letter is greater then return -1;
            return -1;
    }
    return 0;  //if both the equal then return 0
}
```