# Java: How can I tell if one of my array String values is null?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

After many failed attempts to alphabetically sort an array, I have realized my failure is most likely due to one of my String array values being null. I tried both Arrays.sort() & compareTo(), much like this user:
   [How to sort a String array alphabetically (without using compareTo or Arrays.sort)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689672/how-to-sort-a-string-array-alphabetically-without-using-compareto-or-arrays-sor)

...with the same results, most likely pointing to one of my values being null. How can I tell if one of my values is/are null? Is there a test? How did it get to be null? And most importantly, is this even the correct question to be asking? Thanks.

```
     String[] titleChoice = new String[5];
     String title = "", titleString = "";
     String[] authorChoice = new String[5];
     String author = "", authorString = "";
     int[] pageChoice = new int[5];
     String page = "", pageInt = "";
     String currentTitle;
     String currentPage = "";
     String formatEntry;

     int x = 0;
     int numEntered;

     int highestTitle = titleChoice.length - 1;
     int highestAuthor = authorChoice.length - 1;
     int highestPage = pageChoice.length - 1;

     final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = 5;

     boolean notQuit = true;

           Arrays.fill(titleChoice, "zzzzzzzzzzz");
           Arrays.fill(authorChoice, "zzzzzzzzzzz");
           Arrays.fill(pageChoice, 99999999);

     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     do
        {

        System.out.print("Enter the title of a book, or zzz to quit:");
           titleChoice[x] = input.next();

        if(!titleChoice.equals("zzz"))
           {
           LibraryBook inputBook = new LibraryBook();
           inputBook.setBook(titleChoice[x]);

           LibraryBook inputAuthor = new LibraryBook();
           System.out.print("Please enter " + titleChoice[x] + "'s author's last name: ");
              authorChoice[x] = input.next();
           inputAuthor.setAuthor(authorChoice[x]);

           LibraryBook inputPages = new LibraryBook();
           System.out.println("Please enter " + titleChoice[x] + "'s page count: ");
              pageChoice[x] = input.nextInt();
           inputPages.setPages(pageChoice[x]);

           x = x + 1;
           }
           else
              System.out.println("You have elected to quit the program. Goodbye.");
        }
     while(((!titleChoice.equals("zzz")) && x < 5) && ((!authorChoice.equals("zzz")) && x < 5)     
         && ((!pageChoice.equals("zzz")) && x < 5));

    //I just put this in here to see if it would compile
    Arrays.sort(titleChoice[x]); }}
```

Comment: Iterate over all elements in your list, and test each for equality with `null`?

Comment: When you say it fails, what exactly do you mean ?

Comment: A useful trick is to actually read the stack trace you're getting with the exception.

Comment: `boolean containsNull = Arrays.asList(array).contains(null);`

Comment: I think you should first think if you want `nulls` on your data structure or not. Is it some legacy code you have to deal with ? Could you refrain from adding `nulls` in the first place ? that would be easier and would achieve better performance.

Comment: Honestly not really sure how they got there. Just started with Jave 7 weeks ago. I'd love to refrain from having them in there, do you see where I allowed them in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I tell if one of my values is/are null?

One way is to learn to read the stack trace that you are getting.  (We could maybe help you with that, if you showed it to us.)

Another way is to test the value to see if it is null.

> Is there a test?

Here is how you test a simple variable.

```
    if (a == null) {
         System.out.println("a is null");
    }
```

If you have an array whose elements could be `null`, write a loop to test them.  (There are more elegant ways ... but if you are learning, keep it simple.)

> How did it get to be null?

The two ways are:

- You assigned `null` to it.
- It was `null` to start with, and you haven't assigned a non-null value to it.  For example, `new String[5];` creates a new String array whose values are initially all `null`.

> And most importantly, is this even the correct question to be asking?

We can't tell you what the "correct" question is, because it depends on your mental state ... and we cannot read your mind.